# Adding custom functions to Ember.js ArrayControllers

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to figure out Ember.js and keep hitting what seems like basic problems that are not documented in a way I understand.

I want a object to manage a list of stuff. ArrayController seems to make sense. I assume having that controller load the data from the 3rd party server (youtube) makes the most sense. So My plan is to write some custom functions in the controller to load the data.

```
App.videoController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    loadSomeVideos() {
        console.log("I have run");
    }
});
```

after I run the above code App.testController.someFunction() does not exist. Why not? I feel like I am missing some basic concept.

Comment: Firstly you must rename the controller to App.VideoController, from where do you want to call the method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call Ember.ArrayController.extend, you're actually just extending the class not creating a concrete instance, therefore you can't call loadSomeVideos.

There are a few conventions in Ember that can get you stumped if you're unaware of them. As commented by "Unspecified", you should use the following convention to extend the class.

Please note the upper case VideoController and also the way in which I'm defining the loadSomeVideos method:

```
App.VideoController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    loadSomeVideos: function() {
        console.log("I have run");
    }
});
```

Now, if you want to run this, you need to create an instance of the App.VideoController class. Once again notice the capitalisation:

```
App.videoController = App.VideoController.create();
```

So, I use a lower case v for the instance, and an upper case V for the class. I've just created an instance (App.videoController) of the class (App.VideoController).

To call your method, you need to call it from the instance, like this:

```
App.videController.loadSomeVideos();
```

Check out the following two pages in the documentation.

This first page gives you some info about extending classes and then instantiating them so you can call their methods:

http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/classes-and-instances/

The second page goes into a bit of depth about more advanced methods reopen and reopenClass.

http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/reopening-classes-and-instances/